# Dismissing Alert Dialog without Calling Dismiss

Tags: android, dialog, android-widget, android-alertdialog

In my program i am showing Toast for an ***empty edit text***, that edittext ***inside my Dialog along with Upload button***, now about my program and problem

Like:

1. **PersonName** field cannot be left blank
2. If *PersonName field* is Empty then **showing Toast**
   (whenever user do ***tap on Upload button***) in *alert dialog*
3. *Without* calling **dismiss**, it's ***closing my AlertDialog***

In my AlertDialog, i have around **4 EditTexts**, **3 buttons** and some ***other Widgets***.

**UploadActivity.java:-**

```
private boolean SaveData() {                        

 final AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(UploadActivity.this);                    
  ad.setTitle("StreamReader");                        
  ad.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
  ad.setPositiveButton("Close", null);      
  if(editPersonName.getText().length() == 0)
  {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Person Name field cannot be left blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  return false ;
  }
  String 
  url = "http://domain.tld/sendData.jsp";       
  List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sImageName", editImageName.getText().toString()));

  String resultServer  = getHttpPost(url,params);
  Log.d("Entire string::", " " + resultServer);
  /*** Default Value ***/
  String strStatusID = "0";
  String strError = "Data Stored to Server";
  JSONObject c;
  try {
    c = new JSONObject(resultServer);
    strStatusID = c.getString("StatusID");
    strError = c.getString("Message");
       } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
     }
    // prepare save data
    if(strStatusID.equals("0"))
    {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Uploaded Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                           
    }
     return true;
    }
```

Comment: So what is your problem if dialog close ?

Comment: it has to show Toast like showing (when edittext is null) and but don't need to close dialog @GrIsHu  in short i am validating for null don't calling to close dialog

Comment: Then you need to add your code in your `d.setPositiveButton("Close", null);`  click listener. You need to implement it.

Comment: can you elaborate whats happening now and what you really need ?

Comment: I guess, you have to call a method which contains of edited text. From there you validate the edited string and print the toast incase of null or empty. once the string is empty again call the dialog else do whatever you wanna. Hope this will help you out.

Comment: @HariRam can you show me the way, actually i tried several times, but did not get work

Comment: Wanna see some more code @AbrahimNeil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validate your edit text before calling SaveData method. and remove validation code from SaveData :

So handle click event like this :

```
uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                if(editPersonName.getText().length() == 0)
              {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Person Name field cannot be left blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }
                else
                {
                    SaveData();
                }
            }
```

Now your SaveData will look like :

```
private void SaveData() {    

      String
      url = "http://domain.tld/sendData.jsp";      
      List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sImageName", editImageName.getText().toString()));

      String resultServer  = getHttpPost(url,params);
      Log.d("Entire string::", " " + resultServer);
      /*** Default Value ***/
      String strStatusID = "0";
      String strError = "Data Stored to Server";
      JSONObject c;
      try {
            c = new JSONObject(resultServer);
            strStatusID = c.getString("StatusID");
           strError = c.getString("Message");
       } catch (JSONException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
       }

      // prepare save data
      if(strStatusID.equals("0"))
        {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strError.toString(),   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
        else
        {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Uploaded Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                          
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean SaveData() {                        

     final AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(UploadActivity.this);                    
      ad.setTitle("StreamReader");                        
      ad.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
      ad.setPositiveButton("Close", null);   
      return validateAndShare(editPersonName.getText().toString());
```

}

```
private boolean validateAndShare(String editedText){
    if(editedText!= null && !editedText.trim().equals(""))
      {

      String 
      url = "http://domain.tld/sendData.jsp";       
      List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sImageName", editImageName.getText().toString()));

      String resultServer  = getHttpPost(url,params);
      Log.d("Entire string::", " " + resultServer);
      /*** Default Value ***/
      String strStatusID = "0";
      String strError = "Data Stored to Server";
      JSONObject c;
      try {
        c = new JSONObject(resultServer);
        strStatusID = c.getString("StatusID");
        strError = c.getString("Message");
           } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
         }
        // prepare save data
        if(strStatusID.equals("0"))
        {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Uploaded Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                           
        }
         return true;
        }else{

            return false;
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Person Name field cannot be left blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             //Again open the dialog 
             SaveData();

        }
```

I don't know this will work or not. this is my assumption. check it with your code. if it works fine, then upvote for my answer. :)

Comment: You should not suggest a solution when you're not fairly sure it's correct.